# RandomStringUtils.random strange behavior in web application

Tags: java, arrays, random, tostring

I am generation a random password with `RandomStringUtils.random`. It seems to has a strange behavior when generate the password while the application is running, it always create a password with this structure: `[C@1c3f05e5, [C@2b15e4de, [C@18c628b6`. It always repeat the three first characters. My code to generate the password is:

```
char[] password = RandomStringUtils.random(10, 0, 0, true, true, null, 
                new SecureRandom()).toCharArray();
```

If I execute this code in a `main` method, it seems work well.

Comment: Read about toString method!!

Comment: @Jens, `toString` cannot help with arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your `char[] password` array with [`Arrays.toString(char[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char[])) to see the desired result.

EDIT (to comments):

It prints not an object reference, just gets called [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) from `Object`, because of absence its own overridden.

`System.out.print[ln]` calls `toString` from the instance that has been passed, so the following lines are identical:

```
System.out.print(password);
System.out.print(password.toString());
```

But, as I have already said, that doesn't give any useful output. You ought to use

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(password));
```

with arrays, which don't override this method.

Comment: `System.out.println("password.toString()");` this code doesn't display the content.

Comment: @angeldev, yes, you need `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(password));`

Comment: @angeldev, I've added the explanation

Answer (score 2):

You are print the object reference( `[C@1c3f05e5, [C@2b15e4de, [C@18c628b6`) and not the object's content.

Comment: OMG! it is true. But why is it printing the object reference inside the application and the object's content when I run the code in main method?

Comment: Are you using `System.out.println(password);` inside the `main()` method?

Comment: `toString()` method is implicitly called in the `System.out.println()` method for char array. In other place it didn't. You need to understand more about when `toString()` will be called.